# org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Item 0 of 10 did not update any rows: Anyone seen this error?

Tags: spring-batch

org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Item 0 of 10 did not update any rows: I get this error when trying to update records in an ItemWriter using spring batch. Has anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't actually related to Spring Batch itself, rather than data access generally.

Please make sure that your db update/insert query is correct.